Has China occupied any Indian land in Indian North East?
I know that China controls a significant portion of land in Jammu & kashmir and that area is called Aksai Chin. Also, very recently Rahul Gandhi claimed that China has occupied 4000sqkm of land in Ladakh.
Has China occupied any Indian territory in Indian North East (either in Arunachal or in other provinces) and maintain its control on, in relation to the border that India established in 1947?
If so, how much land has China occupied and maintain its control on?
Note: I am not asking about either Aksai Chin or Ladakh.

Maybe rephrasing to something like "what are the border disputes between China and India at this time, besides AC or L?" would sound more neutral.

There are some details here on a couple of villages/"enclaves" they built, but it's not apparent what their area is. In that region is probably difficult to assess who "controls" what in the unpopulated but contested areas.

Cross-posted at Skeptics.SE: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57377 . Cross-posting is highly frowned upon, @user366312.

@DavidHammen, This is not cross- post. Read again.

@DavidHammen The linked question is about a completely different geographical area.

Not in Northeastern India but very nearby in Bhutan, the Doklam plateau is occupied by China and contested by Indian military (on behalf of Bhutan). See https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/what-is-doklams-strategic-importance-for-india-and-china/23532#23532

OTOH that was later contested by Arunchal's CM https://theprint.in/india/no-chinese-village-in-arunachal-construction-is-on-their-side-says-cm-pema-khandu/775351/

The border in the east follows the McMahon line. China does have claims south of the line but the actual control does follow it. Some areas south of the McMahon line were temporarilly occupied during the war of 1962, but China withdrew to the line.
Small incursions and provocations happen from time to time, usually from the Chinese side which has the claims on the areas that India controls. There were clashes in 2021-2022 (mentioned in the other answer, I was distracted by preparing an edit mentioning it) and some incursion reportedly happened very recently (Newsweek: China's Troops Advance Dozens of Miles Across Indian Border: Report
Published Sep 10, 2024).  However, these are really more incursions, rather than occupation of an area beyond the McMahon line.


in relation to the border that India established in 1947

Apparently they recently (~2021) built a village in a contested area that was reportedly captured by China in 1959.

It is located along the disputed border in upper Subansiri district.
“It has been built by China in an area that was occupied by the PLA after overrunning an Assam Rifles post in 1959 in an operation known as Longju incident along the frontier in Arunachal Pradesh,” said one of the officials cited above.

Due to this background, it was denied (e.g. by Arunachal's CM and by the  Chief of Defence Staff) as being built on India's side of the LAC. Nonetheless, India's MFA also seems to have called it "illegal construction". (IMO, the general context of that statement leaves somewhat ambiguous if they referred to this place in particular, or China's efforts in general around the border.)
There are some more details on Wikipedia about Longju.

India had set up a border post manned by Assam Rifles at Longju in 1959, when it was attacked by Chinese border troops and forced to withdraw. After discussion the two sides agreed to leave the post unoccupied. India established a new post at Maja, three miles to the south of Longju, but continued to patrol up to Longju. After the 1962 Sino-Indian War, the Chinese reoccupied Longju and brushed off Indian protests.
Since late 1990s and early 2000s, China has expanded further south, establishing a battalion post at erstwhile Maja. In 2020, China built a 100-house civilian village close to this location in disputed territory.

